# OpenGL buffers and Qt OpenGL module

Tags: qt, opengl, glew

I am going to write an OpenGL application using QT as windowing utality. but i have some problems.
when i trying to use OpenGL version>=2.0 functionalities such as shaders and buffer objects, my application craches. I use the `QGLWidget` as rendering widget and this is a snipet of my code :

```
void RenderingWidget::initializeGL()
{
    GLuint buffer_id;
    glGenBuffers(...)
          .
          .
          .
}
```

and it fails.
on the other side when i create buffers and shaders through `QGLBuffer` and `QGLShader` classes, buffers and shaders being created properly but only fragment shader works and vertex buffer do nothing. what is the solution?
if matters i access OpenGL version>=2.0 functionalities through `GLEW` extensions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you access advanced OpenGL functionality through *GLEW*. So did you remember to properly initialize *GLEW* by calling `glewInit()` after getting the OpenGL context (most probably as first statement in `initializeGL()`)? Otherwise the neccessary function pointers won't be set up properly, which should indeed result in some kind of access violation or null pointer dereference when calling functions like `glGenBuffers`.

On the other hand Qt does its own manual extension management internally, without using *GLEW* or anything, which is why the Qt features for buffer or shader management work properly.